# Xcode 9, watchOS4, no longer showing 15% background CPU limit?

Tags: ios, xcode9, watchos, watchos-4

With Xcode 9.0 and watchOS 4, it looks like when the app is doing work in the background (say in a HKWorkoutSession), the CPU Report tool within Xcode does not show the CPU average/cap and the 15% threshold max.

I'm unable to find documentation on the rule being removed, so I'm curious as why the feature no longer appears to be there.

[CPU tool prior to Xcode 9/watchOS 4 shows that the CPU tool has an average/cap and usage limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmGLC.png)

[CPU tool in Xcode 9/watchOS 4 missing average/cap/usage legend and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7WRv.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those experiencing the same problem:

I did reach out to an Apple Engineer who confirmed that this is a bug with Xcode.